# How to mock constructor with methods as an parameter using EasyMock?

Tags: easymock

I want to test method "make()" using EasyMock. Inside a method there is a new object created with parameters. I wanted to know, how to write test case for the same using EasyMock ?

```
private void make(final Parent p) {
    fun = new Fun(getMethod1(), getMethod2(), getMethod3(), getMethod4());
    fun.setBorder(120);
    p.add(fun);
}

private ProductSpecification getMethod1() {
    return getSequence();
}

//XYZ.class
@Override
public T getSequence() {
    return this.sequence;
}

public View getMethod2() {
    return view;
}

public Info getMethod3() {
    return this.info;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do it with EasyMock. Some will tell you that you can mock the instantiation using PowerMock.

But it generally means a flaw in your design. I personally never use PowerMock.

The questions to ask are:

1. Do I really need to mock that instantiation? If it's just some data, it's probably not needed
2. If I need to, should I extract a class or a method?

The answer to question 2 depends on how you will use it later.

If I extract a class, I will have

```
private final FunFactory funFactory;
private void make(Parent p) {
    fun = funFactory.create(getMethod1(), getMethod2(), getMethod3(), getMethod4());
    fun.setBorder(120);
    p.add(fun);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    Fun fun = mock(Fun.class);
    FunFactory funFactory = mock(FunFactory.class);
    expect(funFactory.create("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4")).andReturn(fun);
    replay(fun, funFactory);
    // do the test
}
```

And if I extract a method, I will have the following.

```
private void make(Parent p) {
    fun = createFun(getMethod1(), getMethod2(), getMethod3(), getMethod4());
    fun.setBorder(120);
    p.add(fun);
}

Fun createFun(String m1, String m2, String m3, String m4) {
    return new Fun(m1, m2, m3, m4);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    Fun fun = mock(Fun.class);
    Make make = partialMockBuilder(Make.class)
        .addMockedMethod("createFun")
        .createMock();
    expect(make.createMock("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4")).andReturn(fun);
    replay(fun, make);
    // do the test
}
```